# Restrict sql execution for multiple users in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am new to oracle. I am using oracle database 19c. I need to restrict the query execution in such a way that if a query is executed once, concurrent execution should get warning or wait until the first query is complete.

**Example:**

```
--First time execution
select count(*) from table;

--At the same time, another user execute the query
select count(*) from table; <<== Either wait or get a warning
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: We can not stop different user from viewing same row. Can you explain what are you trying to achieve with this.

Comment: I am trying to stop recursive execution of a particular statement. Is there any way to enqueue the select statement similar to DML from database like triggers ? I am aware that select statement is readable with read consistency